# How to extend static inherited array in PHP class

Tags: php, class, static

Let's say I have a static array and I would like to add some more values into it in a child class. Since PHP does not have static constructor, I really don't know how to achieve this in a clean manner (I definitely don't want to add anything under the class definition and can't change the autoloader)

This is what I would like to achieve (obviously doesn't work)

```
class Parent{
    public static $meta = [1,2,3];
}

class Child extends Parent{
    public static $meta = array_merge(parent::$meta,[4,5]);

}
```

Comment: I'd recommend you to create singleton class that would share static information between classes you want.

Answer (score 2):

What you want isn't possible with vars inside classes. Instead I would suggest to provide the acccess to the var over an getter method. On top of this, I would suggest to make the static var protected, to prevent unwanted access from outside.

Using late static binding, you could provide a static function in the parent class, which merges the own var with the vars from the inherited class.

```
class A {
    protected static $meta = [1,2,3];

    public static function getMeta() {
        if (__CLASS__ == static::class) {
            return self::$meta;
        }
        return array_merge(self::$meta, static::$meta);
    }
}

class B extends A {
    protected static $meta = [4,5];
}

var_dump(B::getMeta());
```

The comparison of `__CLASS__ == static::class` is only needed for this example - if you go with assiciative arrays and just want to append new options, you could just ignore this and use a simple `return self::$meta + static::$meta;`

Keep in mind, this works only for one level inheritance. If you need a cascade of new $meta vars in the child classes, you have overwrite the getMeta method in the child classes too.

Comment: But calling A::getMeta() would return [1,2,3,1,2,3] which is a weird behavior

Answer (score 1):

you are redefining an attribute in your child class which is not recommended. You can check [here](https://github.com/kalessil/phpinspectionsea/blob/master/docs/architecture.md#class-overrides-a-field-of-a-parent-class) alternatives

Moreover parent is not an allowed name for a class. A solution would be to implement a static method wich return the property. Like this

```
class ParentClass{
    public static $meta = [1,2,3];

    public static function getMeta() {
        return self::$meta;
    }
}

class Child extends ParentClass{
    public static function getMeta() {
        return array_merge(parent::getMeta(),[4,5]);
    }
}

var_dump(Child::getMeta());
```

Result is

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  int(1)
  [1]=>
  int(2)
  [2]=>
  int(3)
  [3]=>
  int(4)
  [4]=>
  int(5)
}
```

You can check this live here : https://3v4l.org/v8Mtm

Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can imagine doing this (without using a constructor or adding to the the class definition) is to use define consts like so;

```
/* FOO CLASS FILE */
define('FOO_META', [1, 2, 3]);

class Foo{
    public static $meta = FOO_META;
}

/* BAR CLASS FILE */
define('BAR_META', array_merge(FOO_META, [4, 5, 6]));

class Bar extends Foo{
    public static $meta = BAR_META;
}

echo 'Foo-Meta = ' . implode(', ', Foo::$meta) . '<br>';
echo 'Bar-Meta = ' . implode(', ', Bar::$meta) . '<br>';
```

Class properties can only be assigned const values inside the class definition. You will need to use a constructor (or some other method) to do this dynamically. If you use the above method, I would recommend using namespaces like so:

```
define('foo\META', [1, 2, 3]);
define('bar\META', array_merge(foo\META, [4, 5, 6]));
```

**EDIT:** if these classes consist only of this one property, why not just use the defines by themselves? They are essentially the same thing without the additional overhead.